# Advantage of setting name to RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There are API available for assigning name to RDD .

For example

```
val y = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3))
y.setName("New Name")
```

What is the advantage of it ? Any specific reason for this feature to be available in Spark?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you cache it, you can see the name in Spark's Web UI on the Storage tab.

Comment: thanks Marius Soutier. Will there could be any other advantage of this feature?

Comment: Not only when you cache it - if you look at the job's "DAG Visualization" in the UI, you'll see it there too. That could be useful for differentiating jobs from one another.

Comment: But there is no method for getting the name??

Answer (score 1):

In the source code of the [RDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala) says this:

```
/** A friendly name for this RDD */
  @transient var name: String = null

  /** Assign a name to this RDD */
  def setName(_name: String): this.type = {
    name = _name
    this
  }
```

So really is in order to be helpfull for the user in order to add a new control to RDD with a name choosen by the programmer. always is good to have a field to describe or name an object, for identification, security, operations permitted, logging ...