# How to set a name for underlying cached RDD for Spark's Matrix data type

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

When cache'ing a [BlockMatrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/mllib-data-types.html#blockmatrix), I call `.cache()` on it (and then force eval it), but how can I [set a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061899/advantage-of-setting-name-to-rdd) to it for easy identification on Spark's UI console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `setName` on `blocks`:

```
matrix.blocks.setName("foo")
```